# Custom sprite shader rendering incorrectly when something is in front of it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to shaders, and I just made one for 2D sprites. The problem is when I move any sprite in front of a sprite using my shader (including sprites that are also using my shader).

In this example, the sprites aligned to the grid are using my shader, and the sprite in the center is using Sprites-Default.

Behind, which works as you would expect:

[image: something is rendered behind my shader]

In Front, which renders the other sprite(s) on top for some reason:

[image: something is rendered in front of my shader]

Things I've tried:

[SubShader Tags](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SubShaderTags.html), [Blending](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SubShaderTags.html), and messing around with Render Queue. But maybe I just missed something obvious from there.

I've also looked for someone with a similar issue with no luck.

Here is the actual shader:

```
Shader "Custom/Normal2D"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Normal("Normal", 2D) = "white" {}
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        {
            "Queue" = "Transparent"
            "RenderType" = "Transparent"
        }

        Pass
        {
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float3 normal : NORMAL;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            v2f vert(appdata v) {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex, _Normal;
            float _Up, _Dn, _Rt, _Lt;
            //up, down, left, right

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target {
                float4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                float4 normal = tex2D(_Normal, i.uv);
                float2 n = float2(normal.a * 2 - 1, normal.g * 2 - 1);

                float dt = 1; //dot
                if (distance(float2(0, 0), n) > 0.01) {
                    n = normalize(n);

                    bool Rt = (n.x > 0), Lt = !Rt;
                    bool Up = (n.y > 0), Dn = !Up;

                    /**/ if (Rt && Up) dt = dot(n, float2(_Rt, _Up));
                    else if (Rt && Dn) dt = dot(n, float2(_Rt, _Dn));
                    else if (Lt && Up) dt = dot(n, float2(_Lt, _Up));
                    else if (Lt && Dn) dt = dot(n, float2(_Lt, _Dn));

                    dt = (dt + 1) / 2;
                    dt += 0.5;
                }

                return float4(color.r * dt, color.g * dt, color.b * dt, color.a);
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shader is Ok in general, but sprites shaders have to respect [sorting layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TagManager.html), but it looks like zbuffer interfering with it, try adding `ZWrite Off` like this:

```
// ... your code

Pass
{
    ZWrite Off
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

// ...your code
```

Comment: i suspected that was the issue it but wasn't really sure